# What package can I use for HTTP Request description?

Tags: api

Is there a way to format a HTTP request like this, like when using `http` with markdown?

```http
PATCH /v1/something/1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Api-Key: supersecretkey
Content-Length: 107

{
    "date": "2023-03-15 05:39",
    "status": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the package `minted`. Pygemtize supports the lexer `http`. You could check this with: `pygmentize -L lexers`.

```
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{minted}{http}
PATCH /v1/something/1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Api-Key: supersecretkey
Content-Length: 107
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[]{js}
{
    "date": "2023-03-15 05:39",
    "status": 0
}
\end{minted}
```